# debian unstable crash

Tags: debian, systemd-nspawn, unattended-upgrades

Debian unstable, running in an nspawn container on Debian Jessie, crashed.

On the host:

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-nspawn@unstable-srv
● systemd-nspawn@unstable-srv.service - Container unstable-srv
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-nspawn@.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-05-31 15:02:51 BST; 6h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-nspawn(1)
 Main PID: 15693 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 31 15:02:51 brick systemd[1]: systemd-nspawn@unstable-srv.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 31 15:02:51 brick systemd[1]: Unit systemd-nspawn@unstable-srv.service entered failed state.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

Journal inside the container.  Last log messages are from unattended-upgrades (with needrestart in automatic mode):

```
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: Restarting services...
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]:  systemctl restart apt-cacher-ng.service console-getty.service cron.service
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Stopping Regular background program processing daemon...
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Stopping Console Getty...
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Stopping Apt-Cacher NG software download proxy...
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv cron[7230]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Stopped Regular background program processing daemon.
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv cron[7230]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Stopped Console Getty.
May 31 14:02:44 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Started Console Getty.
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Stopped Apt-Cacher NG software download proxy.
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Starting Apt-Cacher NG software download proxy...
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt-cacher-ng[7231]: WARNING: No configuration was read from file:sfnet_mirrors
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv systemd[1]: Started Apt-Cacher NG software download proxy.
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: Unable to get Terminal Size. The TIOCGWINSZ ioctl didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: Services being skipped:
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]:  systemctl restart apt-daily.service
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]:  /etc/needrestart/restart.d/dbus.service
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]:  systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]:  systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: Unable to get Terminal Size. The TIOCGWINSZ ioctl didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: No containers need to be restarted.
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: Unable to get Terminal Size. The TIOCGWINSZ ioctl didn't work. The COLUMNS and LINES environment
May 31 14:02:45 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
May 31 14:02:46 unstable-srv apt.systemd.daily[4911]: All upgrades installed
-- Reboot --
May 31 20:41:49 unstable-srv systemd-journald[13]: Journal started
```

The timestamps here line up as you'd expect - I haven't set the timezone inside the container, so the timestamps are out by one hour exactly.

1. Is there anything else I should look for?
2. Does this suggest some additional logging/monitoring that would be useful to help debug such issues?
3. Does the crash look familiar to anyone?

---

EDIT1:

unattended-upgrades-0.93.1+nmu1 
needrestart-2.11-3

systemd-232-24, **upgrade shown in this log takes systemd from 232-23 to 232-24** (according to dpkg.log)

EDIT2:

Attempted to reproduce by downgrading systemd components to 232-23 (using Debian testing), then manually re-triggering `apt-daily.service`.  It upgraded successfully, but did not crash the container again.

I also installed `apt-listchanges` now, to log some information about upgrades when they are installed.